# Hidden folder in Jasper repository

Tags: jasper-reports, ireport, jasperserver

On **creating a report via iReports**, called "Test", iReports will create a **hidden folder** in the repo called "Test_files".

You can see these folders through the **database** in the table `jiresourcefolder`, because it has a column called `hidden`.

```
id | version | uri | hidden | name | label | description | parent_folder | ...
```

You **cannot access** the folders through the default GUI, nor through anything else **but the database and the webservice**, if you **explicitly** request the ResourceDescriptor of the folder.

Now my **question**: Is there any **option or property** (inside the resource descriptor) that can bet set to hide or unhide a folder or even other resources?